# How to select the stock whose amount is the biggest in specified day?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table structure:

```
describe  stock.quote;
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code   | text            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date   | date            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| open   | double          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| high   | double          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| low    | double          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| close  | double          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| volume | bigint(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

show create table quote;
CREATE TABLE `quote` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Search stock whose volumne is the biggest in the date `2020-08-24`:

```
use stock;
select * from  quote where volume=(select max(volume) from quote where date='2020-08-24');
+---------+------+------------+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
| id      | code | date       | open   | high  | low  | close  | volume    |
+---------+------+------------+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
| 5994509 | ontx | 2020-08-24 | 0.2752 | 0.398 | 0.26 | 0.3429 | 179162144 |
+---------+------+------------+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
1 row in set (19.46 sec)
```

Suppose amount = close * volume ,how to get the stock info whose amount is the most biggest in the date `2020-08-24`?

Comment: please always give table structure by showing the output of e.g. `show create table quote`; it is so much more helpful

Comment: Sorry , if I am asking something wrong but you do have a query already , is it not working ?

Comment: I want max(close*volume) instead of max(volume).

Comment: Use simple `ORDER BY volume DESC LIMIT 1` or `ORDER BY volume*close DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Akina:

```
select * from quote where date='2020-08-24' ORDER BY volume*close DESC LIMIT 1;
```